# powershell browsing to a file path

Tags: powershell

In a powershell script, how do I use a common file path.
For ex: 
$file_path=c:\users\documents 
Under documents, I need to operate on 2 folders - "updates" and "archives"

In the script, how do I browse to updates, archives?
I tried $file_path\updates. But that didn't work.

Example, copying a file:
copy c:\users\documents\new_file.txt c:\users\documents\updates

Instead of the full path, I would like to use 
copy $file_path\new_file.txt $file_path\updates\

Comment: You mean like `cd $filepath\updates`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include [mcve] of what you have tried.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, yes like cd $file_path\updates

Comment: Sure, you can do that. What's the problem? Are you getting error messages? If so, what do the error messages say?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I tried and it worked! The changes were no different than before. Thanks. I guess posting here did help.

Answer (score 2):

```
param(
    [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$filePath = "c:\users\documents",
    [string[]]$subFolders = @("updates", "archives")
)

Join-Path $filePath -ChildPath $subFolders[0]
Join-Path $filePath -ChildPath $subFolders[1]

[System.IO.Path]::Join($filePath, $subFolders[0])
[System.IO.Path]::Join($filePath, $subFolders[1])
```